# pass data from a form to a different page

Tags: php, html, curl

I have a form (Code Below) that will collect an email address and what I want is that it will then pass the collected email address to the next page to say something like "We have sent the information to email@email.com"

So page 1 will contain the form and will pass the email address to page 2

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="111111111" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="website" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.website.com/getstarted/" id="redirect_1ab97d9c11111111161e5b4a75554" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />

<input class="textbox_1" id="awf_field-111111111" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="500"  />
</p><br />

<p><input type="submit" class="textbox_button" value="" name="cmdSubmit" tabindex="501" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Would you mind reformulating this a bit? I fail to understand what you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem? You have an input named email, if you visitor puts its email address yhere it will be sent to addlead.pl together with the rest of the form.

Page 2 is written in Perl, according to the extension, so you should tag your question accordingly: you won't find much help on Perl with a question tagged as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want the PHP code to get the information in the other page ?

```
$_POST['NAME OF THE FIELD']
```

EXAMPLE

```
$_POST['meta_web_form_id']
```